# XPath query to match no value

Tags: xml, xpath

Does XPATH provide a query that always returns no value?

For example, given this simple XML:

```
<foo>
    <bar>hello, world</bar>
</foo>
```

an XPATH query of the type `//noelement` would obviously return no element, which is fine but it feels like a hack.

I am wondering if the spec mandates a reserved value that would never match any element. Something like `//NIL` that would be a valid XPATH query and at the same time never match any element.

Answer (score 4):

James Clark (XPath 1.0 Editor) [wrote](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/xsl-editors/2000JulSep/0072.html):

> Re: Best practice regarding empty node-set initialization
>
> I like "/..".  We did consider adding a function to return an empty node-set,
> but it didn't really see to buy anything over "../".

Of course the second xpath expression in his mail is a typo.

Therefore if you want to code like a classic use "/..": The parent of the root node does not exist by definition. Good XPath engines should recognize this expression and optimize it to an empty node-set.

Comment: Indeed `lxml.etree` (the Python parser I'm using) seems to recognise it as an empty node set. Interesting concept. Thank you